# How to make specific row child editable in GtkTreeView

Tags: c, treeview, gtk

I am confused as to how to set the "editable" property to a specific child of a GtkTreeView, instead of the entire cell renderer.

```
|  Column  |
[+] Parent
 |__ Child
 |__ Child2 <-- Press to edit
```

---

I didn't seem to find a way to do that.

Comment: Use an editable cell renderer. There is an [`editing-done`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCellEditable.html#GtkCellEditable-editing-done) signal which you can connect to apply result of editing to the underlying data. If you want to edit a specific cell programmatically use [`gtk_tree_view_set_cursor_on_cell ()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#gtk-tree-view-set-cursor-on-cell) to select cell and then [`gtk_cell_renderer_start_editing()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCellRenderer.html#gtk-cell-renderer-start-editing)

Comment: There are already some similar Q/As in SO which may help as well, e.g. [SO: Difficulty in editable GtkTreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23893896/7478597). The [GTK+ By Example/Tree View/Editable Cells](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GTK%2B_By_Example/Tree_View/Editable_Cells) might help also.

Comment: @Scheff In order to use `gtk_tree_view_set_cursor_on_cell` and `gtk_cell_renderer_start_editing` to simulate editing, there is still the need to set the "editable" property to TRUE, to the entire renderer. As for the editing-done and other similar signals, sure I can filter which cell to be really edited or not, but in a generic program design, you don't want to show a text entry box where it is not meant to be edited.

Comment: I must admit that 1. I used gtkmm and 2. I moved to Qt a few years ago. But if I remember right, you can set cell renderers individually per column. Hence, use editable cell renderers for columns you want to have editable, and non-editable cell renderers else. (I remember that I did it this way in gtkmm.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add another boolean column to your ListStore. Then set your Renderer editable property to that extra column.

Sorry, I don't know the C code for a short example.

Comment: I am using TreeStore. Also you can still write the example in your preferred language. Someone /or me/ might just edit and convert it to C.

Comment: Yes. Additional properties in the model which are considered in cell renderers is even more powerful. (You can selectively re-format cells e.g. make individual cells bold or color-highlighted.)